# Reloading a page in the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right now I have a button that reloads the page if a user wants to.

```
<input type="button" value="Refresh Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in the background and just have it update the page when done instead of having them wait while the page refreshes.

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't a "Refresh Page" button refresh the page? You'll basically want to use AJAX to refresh the contents of the `<body>` tag. This will avoid reloading the `<head>` contents

Comment: When what is done?

Comment: Or a hacky solution is to cut the content of the body, wait a millisecond, then paste it back

Comment: If you want to refresh or load some particular data that are coming from server then instead of reloading u can use ajax to load that data.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something I threw together with jQuery. I just loads the current page you are on via ajax and replaces the current HTML body with the new one:

```
$.ajax({                            //Reload current page via ajax
  url: location.href,
  success: function(response) {
    var dummy = $("<div></div>");      //Create a dummy html object to parse response
    dummy.html(response);
    new_body = $("body", dummy);
    $("body").html(new_body);      //Replace 
  }
});
```